# Parse query not passing on PFObject pointer relation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So, what I have is a table named Votes, table User and table Venue. I have pointer relation in Votes to User and Venue. Venue is subclassing PFObject.  This is the way I set the objects to the database:

```
let votes = PFObject(className: "Votes")
votes["venue"] = venue
votes["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
```

And this is working as expected, I can see both objects in the dashboard. But when I try to fetch a Votes row, the Venue object is not passing the query. Any ideas why this is happening. The query:

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()
let query = PFQuery(className: "Votes")
query.whereKey("venue", equalTo: venue)
query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(...)
```

Comment: `query.whereKey("vote", equalTo: venue)`  it seems `vote` should be `venue`

Comment: Oops, I was testing something and forgot to return to the original code. Thanks for noticing, unfortunately that's not the issue.

Comment: What do you mean 'the Venue object is not passing the query' ? How are you testing this? What do you see in the parse logs?

Comment: I mean that the query doesn't call its completion block and there is nothing to see in the logs.